# Python: Classes: Turtle: addFrog() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, class

The following is the code that I have written
What I am trying to run in IDLE is:

```
 >>> mike = Frog('Mike', 'yell')
 >>> course = RaceCourse()
 >>> course.addFrog(julie)
TypeError: addFrog() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

My code for this specific part:

```
def addFrog(self):
    self.turtle.pu()
    spacing = 350/(Frog.lastBib+1)
    Frog.height -= spacing
    self.turtle.goto(-250, Frog.height)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting a `TypeError` is because the `addFrog()` function is only defined to take *1* parameter.

Here's the function fixed:

```
def addFrog(self, frog):
    self.turtle.pu()
    spacing = 350/(Frog.lastBib+1)
    Frog.height -= spacing
    self.turtle.goto(-250, Frog.height)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python when you call a class method using its object it automatically passes self as argument.

In your case, while calling you are providing one variable 'julie'.

So you have to prepare function to take second argument as well 
like:

```
def addFrog(self, julie):
    # body
```